# How do I write php code to check if checkbox is checked or not?

Tags: php

How do I write php code to check if checkbox is checked or not ?
 if checkbox is selected then `YES` value stored in the database, and if checkbox is not selected, then `NO` valued stored in  the database. How to do that?
I know how to connect database etc. thanks

Comment: Please take a look at the related questions on the right of this one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="YES" />

$cb1 = ($_POST['cb1'] == 'YES')?'YES':'NO';
```

If the checkbox is not clicked the value will be null i.e. the variable $_POST['cb1'] will not be set.

Comment: this will trigger E_NOTICE. You should try using `isset($_POST['cb1'])` instead of `$_POST['cb1'] == 'YES'`

Answer (score 5):

If a checkbox isn't checked, it won't be in the HTTP body of your post, so you'll have to check if it's set. You can obviously do that with a simple if statement, or with the ternary operator:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="foo" value="yes" />
```

Then on the PHP side of things:

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['foo'] ) ) {
         $foo = 'YES';
    }
    else {
         $foo = 'NO';
    }

    // shorter though:
    $foo = isset( $_POST['foo'] ) ? $_POST['foo'] : 'no';

    echo $foo;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you know how POST and forms work in HTML.

All you have to do is put a check-box control inside a form and give it a `"name"` attribute.

Then when the form posts back to the server you can check `$_POST["YourNameHere"]` and get the value eg:

```
$val = $_POST["key"];
```